# Retaining Focus for KeyboardListener

Tags: java, swing, clojure

I have a JFrame which contains most everything in the application. It has a `KeyListener` attached, and it also has several buttons and textfield on it. The problem it, when a button is clicked or a textfield is selected, it gets focus and shortcuts don't work. Of course, one can tab out of them, but to do this you must tab through EVERYTHING (each button, each textfield) before giving the window focus again.

Is there a sensible way to only require one <kbd>tab</kbd> to return focus to the frame from the textfield, and no tabs to return focus to the frame from a button click?

A WindowListener doesn't seem like the best way to do this, but if it's the only way I suppose I can forge forward there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many JFrames is there ???

Comment: and listening by KeyListener ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It has a KeyboardListener attached

I have never heard of the KeyboardListener class so I can only guess what you are trying to do.

My guess is that you should NOT be using a listener of any kind.

Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

Comment: Edited my question; I meant KeyListener. That does make sense though, thank you: I will look into using Key Bindings!

Answer (score 3):

If you only need this for the textfield, you can add a keyListener to the textfield and when the user presses tab use yourJFrame.requestFocus(). Otherwise refer you may want to use a window manager or a key map.